# MySQL Join Table on Random Like

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join a table using a like and returning a random result.

Essentially I'm just to join on a domain to subdomain format...

eg:
Domain: indonesian.dating
Subdomain (Potential Matches): asia.indonesian.dating or bandung.indonesian.dating etc.

[image]

One Query I've been trying is:

```
SELECT b.domainname subdomain, a.*
FROM facebook AS a
JOIN domains AS b ON a.domainname LIKE '%testing.dating' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
WHERE 
a.datetime < NOW();
```

Note: the facebook table has 130 domains and the return result needs to have one random subdomain for each of the 130 facebook domains. eg:

indonesian.dating -> bule.indonesian.dating
africa.dating -> lagos.africa.dating
japanese.dating -> tokyo.africa.dating.

and if the query was run again the subdomain would change as they are Random...

Is this possible? I can do a separate query for the subdomains but would much rather use one domain...

thanks
adam

Current Query - Group By not working yet...
Note: handle is a unique value like the domain names in facebook table...

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT b.domainname subdomain, a.*, a.handle
FROM facebook AS a
join domains b on b.domainname like concat("%",a.domainname)
WHERE 
a.datetime < NOW()
ORDER BY RAND()
) AS FBPages
GROUP BY handle
```

Comment: Is the join column a real join? I mean, is the `join domains b on a.domainname=b.domainname` clause meaningful?
In this case, is it a valuable option to rewrite your query as

`SELECT b.domainname subdomain, a.*
FROM facebook AS a
JOIN domains AS b ON a.domainname = b.domainname
WHERE 
a.datetime < NOW()
and a.domainname LIKE '%testing.dating' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`?

Comment: LIKE '%testing.dating' - this value needs to change - there are 130 domains I want to match a random subdomain from. If it was just the one I would do as you said... thanks for trying :)

Comment: what about `join domains b on b.domainname like concat("%",a.domainname)`?

Comment: Hey thanks so much... its not perfect (as I get multiple rows) but it is join an returning subdomains so its a great step forward... I'll see what I can do around limiting the rows returned per domain.  thanks again!!

Comment: why it does return multiple rows? didn't you add the "where ... order by rand() limit 1" at the end of your query?

Comment: the facebook table has 130 rows and the domains table has 2500 rows with many subdomains. The 130 rows joins to many subdomains and returns these... join domains b on b.domainname like concat("%",a.domainname) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 - added order and limit to the join doesn't work... I'll play with it..

Comment: where did you put the "order by"? after the concat() or after the where? It should go after where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reordering the query:

```
SELECT b.domainname subdomain, a.*
FROM facebook AS a
JOIN domains AS b ON a.domainname LIKE concat('%', b.domainname)
WHERE 
a.datetime < NOW()
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: To work properly, the group by clause needs an aggregation function.
Consider adding a sum(), count(), group_concat() or whatever you need to make the "group by" meaningful